# Need help pulling spotify id from uri

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to pull the spotify id from a spotify uri (e.g. spotify:track:5xioIP2HexKl3QsI8JDlG8) I know this should be quite easy, but I can't seem to get anything to validate on http://regexpal.com/.

What I have so far is:

```
spotify:track:[a-zA-Z0-9]{22}
```

But it pulls the whole string, how can I make it only pull after the colon?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to leave that out. PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression is fine, but you need to group the id part (with `()`), so that it can be captured:

```
$str = "spotify:track:5xioIP2HexKl3QsI8JDlG8";
if (preg_match('/spotify:track:([a-zA-Z0-9]{22})/', $str, $re)) {
  $spotifyId = $re[1];
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/uTvss)**.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using a capture group, you can also use a [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind), eg

```
if (preg_match('/(?<=spotify:track:)[a-zA-Z0-9]{22}/', $str, $matches)) {
    $id = $matches[0];
}
```

Demo here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/ESKgCD